# What does the absolute value of substituting a point (not lying on a line) into a line means

Tags: proof-writing

I am not sure mathematically, if my understanding to $|Ax_p+By_p+C|$ to be correct. I noticed in a code that it is being used as a kind of distance of a point $P=(x_p,y_p)$ to line L $Ax+By+C = 0$

For that I am asking the question,
what is the difference between the absolute value of substituting a point $P=(x_p,y_p)$ (not lying on a line) to a line $Ax+By+C = 0$ as follows,

$|A x_p + B y_p +C|$

and

Eucludean distance= $\frac{|Ax_p+By_p+C|}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}$

I am curious to understand the numerator of the euclidean distance. In the euclidean distance we are dividing by the magnitude or length of the vector (A,B). But what if I used only the numerator as the distance. What would be the difference between both values?

Another way of seeing it which I found based on this [link](https://brilliantorg-infra-prod.brilliant.org/wiki/dot-product-distance-between-point-and-a-line/),

[image]

to have something relative for the distance between point $P_1$ and line **S**,
$$||\vec{PQ}||cos(\theta) = \frac{a(x_0)+b(y_0)+c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} = \frac{||\vec{PQ}|| ||\vec{n}|| cos(\theta)}{||\vec{n}||}$$

where $\vec{PQ} ||\vec{n}|| cos(\theta) = \vec{PQ}.\vec{n}$
which is the dot product between the vector $\vec{PQ}$ and vector ${\vec{n}}$.

the dot product is the projection (purple line) of one vector $\vec{PQ}$ over the other $\vec{n}$.

If I compared the purple lines can be also used as a kind of relative distances of points $P_1$ and $P_2$ to the line **S**.

Is my understanding correct mathematically or there is a mistake of why $|Ax_p+By_p+C|$ actually works as a distance.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. For example, from the equation $$\text{Euclidean distance} = \frac{|Ax_p+By_p+C|}{A^2+B^2}$$ I can immediately derive $$|Ax_p+By_p+C| = (\text{Euclidean distance}) \cdot (A^2+B^2)$$ Is that what you wanted to know?

Comment: Your expression for euclidean distance (of a point $(x_p,y_p)$ to  line $Ax+By+C = 0$) is wrong, should be $\frac{|Ax_p+By_p+C|}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}$.

Comment: @LeeMosher i am asking what is the difference between the two formulas on the plot. I know that shortest distance is the length of perpendicular line with the division while the other is a longer line but is there a definition for it?